# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.setInstanceSupplier

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am seeing the below exception while starting the `springboot` application.

```
14-12-2020 21:44:07.493 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedGenericBeanDefinition.setInstanceSupplier(Ljava/util/function/Supplier;)V
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.doRegisterBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:258)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:147)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:137)
        at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:157)
        at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:136)
        at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:128)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:691)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:392)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
```

I am working on upgrading the `springboot` version from 1.5.8 to 2.2.12

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>practice</artifactId>
<groupId>com.test.com</groupId>
<version>${revision}${changelist}</version>
<name>practice</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.shade.plugin.version>3.2.1</maven.shade.plugin.version>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <elasticsearch.version>7.5.2</elasticsearch.version>
    <jackson.version>2.8.3</jackson.version>
    <springfox-version>2.7.0</springfox-version>
    <revision>0.0.22</revision>
    <changelist>-SNAPSHOT</changelist>
</properties>


<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-x-content</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.15.Final</version>
        <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jsoniter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoniter</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- This will generate a fat jar, added as a work around for spark-cassandra-connector  -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.shade.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.google</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>shadeio</shadedPattern>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>com.google.**</include>
                                </includes>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <!--<excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>-->
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: It is defintely dependency error because of incompatible depedencies.

Comment: Can you share pom or gradle file

Comment: I have shared the pom file now

Comment: In the future consider putting the version for all relevant dependencies so it's easier to track down the bug and so that even building the same project in the future doesn't give you surprising bugs even if you didn't change anything (it will automatically get latest version for each and they can be incompatible).

Comment: Add the versions of the jars for each of the org.springframework dependancies from the latest successful build + deploy.

Comment: I checked your pom and i see that there are other problems as well. for example : jackson-databind version is wrong

Comment: after removing cassandra dependencies it is working maybe it can help you

Comment: how did you solve this? did you manage to identify incompatible dependencies?